# How to fix Crystal Report Thai language problem

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have develop web application and use Crystal Report.

The problem occur when i use Thai language.

Thai symbol cannot read and its replace with square symbol.

The result have no problem when use CrystalReportViewer on window application (figure 1).

But the problem occur on web site (figure 2), when user request a report, i send the report back with pdf file format.

figure 1: Expecated Result
[image: Expected Reuslt]

figure 2: Problem Result
[image]

The code look like below.

```
rptExternalTransferReport rptH = new rptExternalTransferReport();
rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("/Reports/rptExternalTransferReport.rpt");
rptH.Load();
rptH.SetDataSource([datatable]);
Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

How to fixed this problem.

Help me please.

Edit 17-May, 2011:
Look like the problem is occur when i export to pdf file. 
Because i try use CrystalReportViewer, it have no problem. 
But when export to pdf, the problem occurred.

PS. Sorry for my english writing :)

Comment: Hi, maybe you have to change the charset of the page to UTF-8.. in the source code of the webpage

Comment: Where i have to set UTF-8?. I send via stream, not web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What font you are using?

Please try with "Arial Unicode".I believe the issue is with the fonts - not CR. In order for a font to fully support certain languages (Chinese, Korean, Thai, etc.) the font must support Unicode or be Unicode enabled.

Comment: thanks for this, had problem creating PDF (from HTML) for Thai language (Chinesse, Russian were ok). And this simple solution solve problem. I owe you a beer.

Comment: :) I take a break after long time m back.. Thanks for your offer.. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install Thai language on your machine?

Comment: Of course, my computer is set locale to Thai. And other program can work with Thai language perfectly.